# 500 internal server error caused by mod_fcgid communication error

Tags: php, apache, mod-fcgid

I am getting a 500 internal server error while trying to log into a new script that I just installed on my website - iDevAffiliate

I checked my error file, and am getting the following error:

```
mod_fcgid: process /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper(25026) exit(communication error), get unexpected signal 11
```

I am also getting the following messages:

```
php-cgi[24990]: segfault at 10 ip 000000000059bdd7 sp 00007fff65769a90 error 6 in php-cgi[400000+2c3000]
php-cgi[24993]: segfault at 73000000b8 ip 000000000059bdd7 sp 00007fffff0a3c10 error 6 in php-cgi[400000+2c3000]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated